# Trait 'Livewire\withPagination' not found

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-livewire

quisiera que me ayudaran con este problema. Hice un deployment de mi aplicación en Heroku y resulta que la paginación de livewire me la bota con error. Este es el error que muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi entorno local si funciona todo bien, e incluso ya había echo un deployment de una app con livewire, pero ahora no se cual sería al problema. Les dejo el código de mi clase para que vean la implementación.

```
use Livewire\withPagination;
```

class Carreras extends Component
{

```
use withPagination;

public $search = '';
public $id_;
public $codigo_nivel;
public $nombre_nivel;
public $fk_estado;

private $niveles = [];
private $estados = [];

public function render()
{
    $this->getData();
    $this->getEstados();

    return view('livewire.dashboard.carreras.carreras', [
        'niveles'   => $this->niveles,
        'estados'    => $this->estados
    ]);
}
```

este es mi método para obtener datos:

```
public function getData()
{
    $this->niveles = DB::table('nivel_academico as n')
        ->join('estado as e', 'n.fk_estado', '=', 'e.id_estado')
        ->where('n.nombre_nivel', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->select('n.codigo_nivel', 'n.id_nivel', 'n.nombre_nivel', 'n.fk_estado', 'e.estado')
        ->orderBy('n.codigo_nivel', 'asc')
        ->paginate(8);
}
```

a parte de eso, en la vista solo utilizo `{{ $niveles->links() }}`

No sé que podrá ser el problema, ayuda porfavor!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tener presente que SO ajenos a alguna versión de Windows si son *case sensitive* es decir si distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Dado lo anterior es importante aclarar que [la doc.](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination) infica claramente que la sintaxis es:

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;
```

Dónde como notas el nombre del trait tiene la W mayúscula